# Run .EXE From HTML And JS?

Tags: html, visual-studio-express

I made an project in Visual Studio Express using C#, i compilled it into an .exe, it run normally. is there any way to run my app from HTML, i'm making an website for me.

EDIT: i think is better to make an download and user install the app. thanks for helping :D

Comment: sounds like your project is either windows forms or WPF.  these are desktop apps.  You need Web Forms or MVC for the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You could create a link to the file, and allow people to download it.  Their browser may give them a choice to run it immediately or not.

Comment: i think  i will make an setup for the user then use <a href="C:\Windows\prog.exe">Click Here</a> to open the files.

Comment: You need to put the file on your server with your website, and use a relative path.

Comment: The relative path was a suggestion.  The file needing to be on the same server is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The only I know of to this would be to run an Ajax request and have a server side file execute the file. You can't do it with straight javascript, but if you're willing to use a language like PHP you'll be able to execute a file on your server "using" javascript.